# Assigning static IP addresses to dialin PPP users on Cisco IOS

Tags: cisco-ios, radius, ppp, dialup

I have a Cisco router running IOS 15.3 serving as a dial-in PPP endpoint for a handful of modems. I am using local authentication and a local IP pool to hand out dynamic IP addresses to the callers; this is currently working fine.

I now need to assign static IP addresses to a couple of the incoming callers, preferably based on the username supplied by the calling party during PPP authentication. I understand that this can be done by using RADIUS to authenticate the PPP callers, but I would rather not set that up for such a small installation. This is a small, private installation which does not require any of the other benefits one would normally get from using RADIUS.

Is it possible to assign static IP addresses to incoming PPP users on this platform without using RADIUS? If so, could you describe in general terms how it is done (or point to any relevant documents)?

Comment: This is exactly the kind of task for which RADIUS was invented.

Comment: No. The only way to set the address per user is with AAA (radius/tacacs) There used to be ways to pin an address per line, but it's never been possible by user.

Answer (score 3):

Actually this is relatively easy. Yes, you need AAA, but you don't need an external server.

```
aaa authentication ppp default local
aaa authorization network default local
aaa attribute list Static-1.2.3.4
 attribute type ip-address "1.2.3.4" protocol ip
username static privilege 0 password XXXX
username static aaa attribute list Static-1.2.3.4
```

You can use this method to set pretty much any attribute you'd normally set via RADIUS. I find it quite useful for smaller sites where there is no server as everything's in the cloud, but they still want some users to VPN in for access to things like printers, alarms, or building management systems.

Answer (score 2):

> No. The only way to set the address per user is with AAA (radius/tacacs) There used to be ways to pin an address per line, but it's never been possible by user. – Ricky Beam

I believe Ricky Beam's comment to be correct: there is no way to do this on IOS without using RADIUS.